# Convergence of Fourier series at jump discontinuities

Tags: fourier-series

Suppose $f$ is a bounded piecewise-continuous periodic real-valued function. We assume the function is nice enough so that it has a Fourier series representation that converges to $f$ everywhere. For example, at least assume $f$ is differentiable everywhere except at the jump discontinuities and that $|f'|$ is bounded. Let there be a jump discontinuity at $\alpha$. Also suppose that $f$ is correctly defined at $\alpha$ so that $f(\alpha)=\tfrac{1}{2}\big(\lim_{x\to\alpha^{+}}f(x)+\lim_{x\to\alpha^{-}}f(x)\big)$.  As I have done numerical examples, it seems that the partial sums of the Fourier series (either with or without a kernel like the Fejer kernel) **best** approximate the function exactly at $\alpha$. Slightly away from $\alpha$ the approximation is bad due to the jump discontinuity and the Gibb's effect. However, $\alpha$ and its translates seem to be more special than all other points.  Is there a theorem about this?

Comment: This might be true if the variation in the function away from $\alpha$ is small relative to the jump. Otherwise, you can make the function experience a huge, continuous rise at another place, relative to the jump discontinuity.

Comment: There are continuous functions whose Fourier series diverge at a point, or even at a dense set of points.  Adding a jump discontinuity is unlikely to improve matters.

Comment: Robert, you are correct about that.  A classic example is explained in Volume 1 of the Princeton Lecture Series in Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi. I'm not interested in  pathological behavior.  So, I'll assume whatever is necessary to eliminate weird cases.